# Can I know if any 3rd party Android app is capturing screen recording on my Android mobile app?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, mobile, video-capture

I have a Video chat Android APP. To Provide Privacy is the main USP of my Android APP. I want to provide functionality on my Android app that if someone is trying to capture a screen video using any 3rd party screen video capturing app during video chat then the system will show the warning message. So is there any way or method available that the system knows that any 3rd party is capturing screen video recording so we can show a warning message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to programmatically detect if any screen recording process/app is running in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44544931/how-to-programmatically-detect-if-any-screen-recording-process-app-is-running-in)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FLAG_SECURE` to prevent screen recording.

```
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

in your app entry

```
  public class MyApplication extends Application {
     public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
           
     getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
   }
}
```

[FLAG_SECURE Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE)