# Is there any way where i can detect screen recording/ capturing/screen sharing is on by other application in my android application?

Tags: android, screenshot, screen-recording, android-mediaprojection, flag-secure

I want to detect if any other application started screen recording or screen sharing in my android application and restrict it by showing Dialog. I know Secure_Flag is there to restrict the app content visible to capture/sharing/recording but my use case it i want to allow screen capturing i.e screenshot but restrict sharing/recording. Does the MediaProjectManager will help?

MediaProjectManager I tried. but did not go the solution.

Comment: getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

Comment: LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE Is blocking whole sharing i dont want to stop screenshot. @Shaikh Faizan.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/44545751/6934036 help?

Comment: @MohammadSalehi No, I want to allow screen capture but want to restrict screen recording, mirroring, casting, screen sharing.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/features/screenshot-detection privacy-preserving screenshot detection API. i think this might be help full for you please go through this